# Using ModelBuilder to run clip scenario?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iteration

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I have a layer representing suburbs (n=432) over laid with open space data (both gdb files).

My objective is to get to get the suburbs to individually clip with the open space data, so far everything I have tried has failed. Suburbs with open space traversing the boundary have not been clipped.

I have tried a few models in ModelBuilder with little success. 
Watched numerous YouTube videos on Iterate but nothing appears to match my project.

I am a novice in this area of ArcGIS.

Comment: So, you want to get one clip of 'open space data' for each suburb, is that correct? n=432, does that mean 432 suburbs? Does each suburb, defined by a unique name, have only one polygon (row)? Can you confirm both suburbs and open space are polygon feature classes and not rasters? Have a read of *iterate feature selection* http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm which might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Both datasets are polygons. The suburb layer has "objectid" 1 to 432. thanks for the link. Though it doesn't make it much clear as like to see a model development step by step. Cheers

Comment: If you're trying this by modelbuilder then the iterate feature selection will help, choose OBJECTID as the field and a selection like OBJECTID >= 0 to iterate all your features then use the selected features as your clip feature class, it will contain one feature for each iteration, then put value in your output feature class like Output_Open_Space_%Value%.shp to substitute the inline variable (OBJECTID in this case) into the output name to avoid overwriting your output feature class on each iteration.

Comment: What does your model so far look like and what happened when you tried to run it?

Comment: Thanks Michael, that worked really well. Avoids the thought of doing it manually....

Comment: That's great, can you now answer your own question with screen shots of the important parts of the model please... that tool I found to be not particularly obvious from the Esri help so it would be great to have an answer outlining its usefulness.

Comment: I have taken several snipping tool grabs of the process. I to found the Esri help not very intuitive. I can post my grabs but this forum doesn't have any platform to attach them. Good to have somebody like yourself to help out those of us who are self learning.

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question, that doesn't require a high reputation score, there should be a button on your browser somewhere.. I'm glad that I could be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing a clip only works on one polygon, I had 432 adjoining polygons so a new approach was required other than manually clipping 432 suburb boundaries, a time consuming process. Model builder and the iterate function through the iterate feature selection. Utilizing the field "objectid" within my suburb dataset and the null value >=0. generated the output I_SSC2016_OBJECTID in the selected features. Clip, input feature the open space data and the clip feature: I_SSC2016_OBJECTID. Clicking on the clip OK joined the iterate and clip together. The tick button on the model builder tool bar validated the processes and enabled the Run function to work. The iterate process identified each objectid number and clipped it to the open space data. The processed only saved suburbs that contained open space data to the Catalog as individual gdb files. The merge function rejoined the Output_Clip_Open_Space_1 through to Output_Clip_Open_Space_432 back into one dataset.

[image]